# Spark streaming as event processing/handling solution (micro-services)

Tags: apache-spark, event-handling, spark-streaming, microservices

Spark batch processing is bringing a lot of value to our business since it's very easy to scale horizontally (we use AWS EMR with YARN).

However, a new challenge has arisen as our newest proprietary solution follows a micro-service architecture. So far, there are **~230 micro-services acting as a producer** where the events are stored in Kafka (that means ~230 Kafka topics).

Although we've managed to validate the use of Spark Streaming as event processing to build the lastest state of the objects, am I right saying that I'll need one spark streaming app per Kafka topic (so, ~230 apps)?

If so, our cluster with **48 vCPU** and **192GiB of Memory** can only handle **52 stream processing apps concurrently**. That sounds way too little since those apps (which need to run 24 hours) don't do much as they simply pull events every 5 seconds and perform CRUD operations against our Data Store.

Am I miss using Spark streaming? What other approach or framework would you take/use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound right, you don't need 230 topics for your microservices and you don't need 230 spark streaming apps, you will however use 1 task per partition which means you'll need 230*(partitions per topic) cores to run the 230 or 1 app you decide to build, note it depends on the traffic but your best choice may be to have only 1 topic or a smaller set of topics, filter on consumption. You can subscribe to any amount of topics.
As far as what to use for building state stores, you can look at kafka streams or akka streams. I wouldn't recommend spark streaming for production applications at all (this statement qualifies as opinionated). Akka streams is the easiest API to use IMO, you may need to code your store and API on top of it.

Comment: yeah, I must be missing something obvious. The other non-data-engineering teams' approach here is: for each producer there should be a matching consumer. That's how I came up with 230 streaming app at first.
90% of our topics (e.g. Product, Brands, Retail Price) will have very low traffic with 10s or 100s events per day. I heard good things about Akka. Are you suggesting one stream processing app for a set of topics (based on traffic) where the contract and the parsing logic are deployed as JAR dependency?

Comment: So confluent open sources something called a schema registry you can use for the parsing logic, or you can share code. These days there are different approaches to handle this kind of thing, I like having a single repository, it's the easiest way for all your stuff to be in sync all the time.

I suggest if you have 90% of your topics with that kind of traffic you make them all produce to 1 single topic with 1 partition. Partitions are your unit of parallelisation, if you can handle the traffic easily on one partition you shouldn't put more, and that kind of traffic doesnt' merit more than 1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you guys are doing but I think you have an architectural issue. And I don't understand your organisation enough to know why would they do that. Having hundreds of topics eventually can put unnecessary stress on the cluster, though you can survive the first few hundred. Your initial issue may be tied to spark streaming though, I really recommend you drop that thing though, I don't have anything good to say about it sadly, I can't think of any upside of spark streaming over any other approach.

Comment: @fd8s0...that's was really helpful. Our organisation is quite new to micro-services so it could definitely be an architectural issue that we still need to figure it out ourselves. We'll start by combining those 90% services with low traffic and then take it from there. I'm also considering Akka streams due to the bad reputation of Spark Streaming. Once again, really appreciated.